# Applying two hover effects on Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML code for image and text

```
<div class="subcontainer1">
    <img src="a.png" alt="" class="imgcolumn">
     <h3 class="header3">Hello</h3>
</div>
```

In this **content is placed above image**.

So i was trying to apply two different css effect on single hover.

Like when i hover over div having class **subcontainer1** the `image should shrink` and `text should grow.`

**CSS for shrink and grow**

```
.grow {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.grow:hover, .grow:focus, .grow:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

/* Shrink */
.shrink {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Now is it possible to do so? Or am i just expecting too much from hover??

Comment: Have you tried? What was the result?

Comment: Yeah i tried, but as i am new to coding could not get it up and running. :(

Comment: Can you share what you did (preferably in a jsfiddle) and tell us exactly what did not work?

Comment: Yes you can do that. [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_intro.asp)

Comment: @Richa please see this answer too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547907/applying-two-hover-effects-on-div/24548121#24548121

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
.subcontainer1:hover img { transform: scale(1.1); }
.subcontainer1:hover h3 { transform: scale(0.9); }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JzgF5/

Comment: Your fiddle don't do what the OP want. Is it the right link?

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thanks a lot.Never knew it was so simple. :)

Comment: @NicolasHenrard Rather than demonstrating the exact effects the op were looking for, I'm content to just show OP how to apply certain properties to children of a hovered element. Sort of a learning exercise, if you will.

Answer (score 0):

you should write like this, for example when .subcontainer1 hover add an style to **img** or **h3**

```
 .subcontainer1:hover img{
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }


    .subcontainer1:hover .header3{
       /*Your style*/
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kermani/y97ke/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The .grow and .shrink is not present in html
so in order to make it work
you have you have to use

```
   .subcontainer:hover{
     //css rules
    }
```